# MongoDB shell, $pop works weirdly

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I'm learning MongoDB, and I decided to try a little exercise with the $pop :

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.insert({compteur: 100001, tab:['a','b','c']})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.find({compteur: 100001});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57c011106d76da1c1e34edd2"), "compteur" : 100001, "tab" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$push: {tab: 'd'}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.find({compteur: 100001});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57c011106d76da1c1e34edd2"), "compteur" : 100001, "tab" : [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ] }
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$pop:{tab:1}});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.find({compteur: 100001});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57c011106d76da1c1e34edd2"), "compteur" : 100001, "tab" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$push:{tab:['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.find({compteur: 100001});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57c011106d76da1c1e34edd2"), "compteur" : 100001, "tab" : [ "a", "b", "c", [ "d", "e", "f", "g" ] ] }
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$pop:{tab:3}});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise > db.produits.find({compteur: 100001});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57c011106d76da1c1e34edd2"), "compteur" : 100001, "tab" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
```

I don't understand the logic :

The last pop deleted the array in the array, but why ?

I asked to pop 3, I was thinking it could :

1 - Pop the 3 last entries in the tab inside the tab (So "e", "f", and "g")

2 - Pop the table as a single element, and then pop the 2 element before (So "b" and "c")

Here I am so, I don't understand what happened :/

Comment: Haha, first bug I discover in my career. I'm proud :P

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. Since the last item in the `tab` field is an array, the operation `db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$pop:{tab:3}});` correctly pops the last element (which is the array). The operation the OP is looking for is probably `db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$pop:{"tab.3":-1}});` to pop the first element in the embedded array `"d"`, or `db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$pop:{"tab.3":1}});` to pop the last `"g"`.

Comment: I don't understand the logic so of deleting only a 4-element array when I ask to pop the 3 last elements :/

Comment: `$pop` operator removes the first or last element of an array, the array in this case is a stack. I think you are looking for the [**`$slice`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/slice/#update-array-using-slice-only) operator here.

Comment: Right, there we go. `$pop` doesn't ever remove more than 1 element. So 3 vs. 1 as a value is treated the same.

Comment: So the operator $pop is only capable of deleting a single element ? That's weird, why not making it to allow delete multiple elements ?

EDIT : JohnnyHK can you add a answer but not in comment please, So I can mark this thread as resolved ;)

Comment: @chridam should be the one to add the answer as he figured it out first.

Comment: You're right ! So @chridam 'DO IT ! JUST DO IT !'

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a bug as that's the intended behaviour of the **[`$pop`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/)** operator. It removes the first or last element of an array, the array in this case is a stack and *doesn't ever remove more than 1 element. So 3 vs. 1 as a value is treated the same* (thanks to @JohnnyHK for this quote).

Since the last item in the tab field is an array, the operation

```
db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$pop:{tab:3}});
```

correctly pops the last element (which is the array).

The operation you're looking for is probably

`db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$pop:{"tab.3":-1}});`

which pops the first element in the embedded array "d", or

```
db.produits.update({compteur: 100001}, {$pop:{"tab.3":1}});
```

to pop the last "g".

I think maybe you are looking for the **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/update/slice/#update-array-using-slice-only)** operator here to "pop" multiple elements.